# multiple image upload in database in single input using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to upload multiple images in PHP with single id. But I got only one image uploaded with id in all values.

Specifically, in the below code multiple images upload in database but I got only one value updated for entire images and only one image is storing. In `echo` statement it is showing three different images correctly and MySQL statements 3 individual 111 coming.

```
$id = $_GET['c_id'];

if (isset($_GET['c_id'])){
$id = $_GET['c_id'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    extract($_POST);
    $error = array();
    $extension = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png", "gif");
    foreach ($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"] as $key => $tmp_name) {

        $file_name = $_FILES["files"]["name"][$key];

        $file_tmp = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        //  $ext=pathinfo($file_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        $filename = basename($file_name);
        $newFileName = $filename . '.' . $ext;
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp = $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key], "uploads/" . $newFileName);

        echo $sql = "UPDATE 
     categories c
    LEFT JOIN category_icons e ON e.category_id = c.id SET e.image='$newFileName' where c.id=$id";


        $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE 
     categories c
    LEFT JOIN category_icons e ON e.category_id = c.id SET e.image='$newFileName' where c.id=$id");


        /*  if($sql)
                {
        echo "<script>alert(' Category icons updated successfully'); window.location.href='category.php';</script>";
                }*/
    }
}
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT c.*, e.image,e.id
    FROM  `categories` c
    LEFT JOIN category_icons e ON e.category_id = c.id WHERE c.id='$id'");

$cd_row = mysql_fetch_array($qry);

while ($cr_row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){


?>

<div class="panel-body">


    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="col-md-8">


            <input id="logo" name="files[]" placeholder="logo" type="file">
            <input type="hidden" name="imagehidden" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $cr_row['image']; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $cr_row['image']; ?>" style="float:right;width:120px;height:100px;margin-top: 0px;" class="logo-default">

        </div>


        <a href="javascript:sureToApprove(<?php echo $cr_row['id']; ?>)" style="float:right;" class="btn btn-danger"><em class="fa fa-trash">del</em></a>


        <?php }
        } ?>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info">
            <a href="add_category_icon.php?ci_id=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">add</a>
        </div>


</div>
</form>

</div>
```

What is the problem? If you can find it or any tips for that. Thank you advance.

Comment: UPDATE categories c LEFT JOIN category_icons e ON e.category_id = c.id SET e.image='Chrysanthemum.jpg.' where c.id=21UPDATE categories c LEFT JOIN category_icons e ON e.category_id = c.id SET e.image='Koala.jpg.' where c.id=21UPDATE categories c LEFT JOIN category_icons e ON e.category_id = c.id SET e.image='Hydrangeas.jpg.' where c.id=21 This is echo statement in query place

Comment: Because you are updating all images on same `id` so the last updated record will be reflect. How you want to store multiple images? What is your logic & table struture to store multiple image?

Comment: there are four images with one id i want update all images update with same id with what i want selected image if it not select image should be as same as default

Comment: you'd get more responses if you accepted answers.. just a tip..

Answer (score 0):

You have placed the update query at wrong place.

In your code, what actually happens is, in each loop it will upload file and update image name for the same category id. So in Each loop, it will be overridden with previous value.

What you need to do is, you need to store imageNames of each file in variable, and outside the loop, you need to perform update query with comma separated string.

Please refer below code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  extract($_POST);
    $error=array();
    $extension=array("jpeg","jpg","png","gif");
    $fileNames = array();
    foreach($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name)
            {

             $file_name=$_FILES["files"]["name"][$key];

               $file_tmp=$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];
               //  $ext=pathinfo($file_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

               $filename=basename($file_name);
                  $newFileName=$filename.'.'.$ext;
                   move_uploaded_file($file_tmp=$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key],"uploads/".$newFileName);

                $fileNames[] = $filename;
            }
        $imageFileNames = implode(',',$fileNames);
         $sql= mysql_query("UPDATE 
            categories c
            LEFT JOIN category_icons e ON e.category_id = c.id SET e.image='$imageFileNames' where c.id=$id");   

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: its working but it storing one id with three images in one field but i want with id different columns like 1 penguine.jpg   and  again next column 1 lighthouse.php and again 1 fruit.jpg i want like this

Comment: but its storing 1 penguine.jpg,fruit.jpg,name.jpg like it storing

Comment: any one rly for my question

Answer (score 0):

Code get error Undefined variable: ext in line `$newFileName=$filename.'.'.$ext;` because `$ext` define inside comment.

Here is the complete code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
extract($_POST);
$error='';
$extension=array("jpeg","jpg","png","gif");
$fileNames = array();
foreach($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name)
        {

        $file_name=$_FILES["files"]["name"][$key];

        $file_tmp=$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $ext=pathinfo($file_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            if(in_array($ext, $extension)){
                $filename=basename($file_name);
                $newFileName=$filename.'.'.$ext;
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp=$_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$key],"uploads/".$newFileName);

                $fileNames[] = $filename;
            }else{
                $error ="File extension not support";
            }

        }
    if($error==''){
    $imageFileNames = implode(',',$fileNames);
    $sql= mysql_query("UPDATE categories c LEFT JOIN category_icons e ON e.category_id = c.id SET e.image='$imageFileNames' where c.id=$id");   
    }
    else{
    echo $error;
    }
```

}